# Random href attribute in website address

Tags: jquery, random, href

I am creating one website that uses CSS3 fullscreen gallery. Basically, when i change images my website's address changes. For example, http://www.mysite/index.html#image7 or http://www.mysite/index.html#image20.

I would need a way to display a random image on page load with jQuery or pure JS. I can point to an exact image easily with having this line inside document ready function:

```
document.location.href = "http://www.mysite/index.html#image13";
```

I am not so good with JavaScript, but maybe creating some array of images and then using some randomize function would do the trick?

Any advice?

Comment: Can we see the markup for the images? Are they available on DOM load? Already inserted? i'm assuming it's `<a href="#image13"><img src="blah/blah/blah.blah" /></a>`

Comment: Yes, they are available on DOM load. It is basically a list item.<li id="image1"></li>

Comment: I mean...we can extract the hash, compare it against an LI, and then grab the image. but what do you want to do once we have the image? What's the event you're using to 'galleryify' your images.

Comment: Which CSS3 fullscreen gallery are you using (assuming you didn't roll you own)? That will help us provide answers.

Comment: There is no event involved, cause this is pure CSS3 gallery, no JS is used. I can give you the link to test site: www.madebym.net/test/index.html All i want is random image on page load.

Comment: Something just crossed my mind. Can i have some 15 premade image hrefs, one function to pick a random href and add it to my adressbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i managed to do it myself. I stored some values into an array, and then just used it with document.location.href

```
    var images = [],
        index = 0;

        images[0] = "http://www.mysite/index.html#image13";
        images[1] = "http://www.mysite/index.html#image17";
        images[2] = "http://www.mysite/index.html#image5";

        index = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);

        document.location.href = images[index];
```